# how to get link page keyword in google search engine using meta keyword?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

I am searching a keyword related to my website in Google search engine. But it's showing my website index page title only. It doesn't show related link page. I am using code

```
 <meta name=”robots” content=”index,follow”>  
<meta name="GOOGLEBOT"CONTENT="NOSNIPPET"> 
<meta name="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOARCHIVE">
```

this is index page meta coding.and description also not show in Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following directive you're instructing Google to not display a snippet for the particular page the directive is on:

```
<meta name="GOOGLEBOT"CONTENT="NOSNIPPET">
```

Which means:

> nosnippet:    Do not show a snippet in the search results for this page

See the [full list of accepted robots directives by Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag#valid-indexing--serving-directives)